# BIRT Chart API setting caption to string with equal sign in it truncates value on left

Tags: charts, birt

I'm attempting to use the Chart API directly and am running into a problem with an expression.

If I attempt to do the following

```
chart.getTitle().getLabel().getCaption().setValue("Day of Week (M=1)");
```

The resulting label is:

```
1)
```

If I remove the '=' from the value it works fine no problems but that '=' appears to be triggering an expression evaluation.

Note this is using the Chart Engine API, and this chart is NOT associated with a BIRT Report.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT** It looks like while generating the chart, it attempts to resolve the chart title as a key for an externalized message.  RunTimeContext.externalizeMessage(...) because of the fact that my title contains an '=' sign.  Is there a way to escape this to prevent it from attempting to render it as this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a deeper look into this and was able to fake it out by implementing an externalizer and just keying it to concatenate the key & default values together with the '=' token constant.

as this is for demo purposes it worked ... granted not the most optimal solution but it got what I needed.